# Repetition on a backward look around regular expression

Tags: regex

I'm having issues retrieving a particular set of text from a file name using regular expressions, below you can see what I mean.

From this example I'm interested in extracting "1-2-19".

> 28-3G__1-2-19 02252019.xlsx

From this example I'm interested in extracting "1-5-19".

> 12H-14W_1-5-19 02252019.xlsx

From this example I'm interested in extracting "11-12-18"

> 343X-N_11-12-18.xlsx

Currently the expresion I'm using is:

```
(?<=_)(.*?)(?=( +[0-9]{8})?\.xlsx)
```

Which returns the results I want for the last 2 examples, however, for the first one, it retrieves "_1-2-19", and that extra underscore is giving me issues.

I have tried with repetitions of different sorts, but nothing seems to work. Any idea would be highly appreciated.

These are different approaches I have tried with no success:

```
(?<=(_|__))(.*?)(?=( +[0-9]{8})?\.xlsx)

(?<=__?)(.*?)(?=( +[0-9]{8})?\.xlsx)

(?<=_+)(.*?)(?=( +[0-9]{8})?\.xlsx)
```

Comment: Which tool or language are you using?

Comment: It looks like you're really overthinking this with all the lookaround and capture groups. Something like `\d\d?-\d\d?-\d\d` should be enough, unless that would match false positives in some data that you didn't mention.

Comment: @CAustin I'm using UiPath (Build on top of a .net framework). As you mention, the proposed solution might return false positives, that's why i didn't implement something similar. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first pattern you use 2 capturing groups and the second capturing group (which is located inside the positive lookahead) contains the second value.

Note that `(.*?)` matches any character non greedy except a linebreak and does not take the digit-hyphen pattern into account that you want to match.

What you might do instead is use an optional non capturing group to match a space and 8 digits for the third example and not use any capturing group:

```
(?<=_)\d+-\d+-\d+(?=(?: \d{8})?\.xlsx\b)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=_)` Positive lookbehind to assert what is on the left is an underscore
- `\d+-\d+-\d+` Match 1+ digits hyphen 1+digits hyphen and 1+ digits
- `(?=`Postive lookahead to assert what is on the right is

  - `(?: \d{8})?` Optional non capturing group
  - `\.xlsx\b` Match a dot followed by `.xlsx` Add a word boundary `\b` to check that xlsx is not part of a larger word.
- `)` Close positive lookahead

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XrtKCh/1)

This pattern `\d+-\d+-\d+` can be more specific if you only want 1-2 digits like `\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}`

Comment: The question author is interested in extracting the date string from the filenames, not matching the entire filename.

Comment: I think this does the trick for every scenario I have, thanks for the advise :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`\d{1,2}\-\d{1,2}\-\d{1,2}`

It should match the dates in your examples without picking up on the other text. You can [view your test cases with this regex](https://regex101.com/r/kq9W7i/1) on Regex101.

Note that `\d` is a token for any digit.

Comment: Thanks, this could retrieve false positives for different scenarios that can show up in my system, that's why I didn't implement something like this, but I appreciate the suggestion.